# how to generate user principal or keytab file via programming in kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

We'd like to manage user pricipal or keytab file in web application, how to generate user principal or keytab file  via programming in kerberos ?

Comment: Source code for the `ktutil` Linux command, that manages keytab files - have fun! https://github.com/krb5/krb5/tree/master/src/kadmin/ktutil

Comment: Seriously, quoting an anonymous White House official, *"that shit is hard"*. Read https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html

Comment: Richard, can you please explain in more detail exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish? For one, keytabs contain service principals, not user principals.  Second, once the keytab is created the service principal inside must remain fixed and cannot be modified or else the keytab itself will become invalidated.

Comment: At present ,we can only maintain user principal or generate keytab file with kadmin or kadmin.loca command, we'd like to acheive it by using something  like call kerberos api or some else, I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finallly, I do that in python, doing something like: commands.getstatusoutput('kadmin.local -q "addprinc test"')

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Normally, you could manage principal wih commands as follows: first step : run kadmin or kadmin.local  ,second step: run addprinc or other command to manage principal . Now you could call shell command in python like this: commands.getstatusoutput('kadmin.local -q "addprinc test"') to add principal.